# How to use INT as CHA for all purposes

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, dnd-3e

I am wondering if there is a way to use my INT Ability score as my CHA score, plain and simple.

Basically I would like a feat or something that makes this the case. However, if that is not possible, an item could be a good alternative.

The lower the prerequisites/cost the better as that will determine my effective starting level. But long term methods are acceptable as well.

Primary Systems of acceptance are D&D 3.5 & 3.0 as well as Pathfinder. Other similar systems might work but not as cut and dry.

Comment: Pretty sure this is impossible, as written. Why are you trying to do it? Maybe there's a substitute.

Comment: This is a valid question, but the answer to it is very unlikely to help you or anyone else (because it can’t be done). But nonetheless, I’ve answered it. In order to get *actual help* with your problem, though, I strongly recommend starting a *new* question, and asking specifically about what you’re hoping to achieve.

Comment: I really don't see why this question is so heavily down-voted. It's a valid question. Just because it has a trivial and useless answer doesn't make it a bad question; the asker couldn't have known that *before he asked and got an answer.*

Answer (score 9):

[This thread](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?125732-3-x-X-stat-to-Y-bonus) is the *ultimate* reference to stat substitution.  It has 3.0, 3.5, and Pathfinder resources listed by stat-from (X) and stat-to (Y) (although the latter is a little broken at the moment).

**However**, as KRyan said, there's no "Replace CHA with INT for all purposes" option.

Answer (score 4):

There are no abilities in the game that allow you to simply replace one ability score for another for all purposes. That would be *highly* imbalanced. Rather, there are ways to replace one ability score for another *for some particular purpose*. But even if you stacked all those together to cover every possible use of Charisma, which I’m quite sure is impossible since I don’t think options exist to *cover* every possible use, but even if you did, your Charisma score would still *exist* (which could be a problem for, e.g., Charisma damage). No creature can have no Charisma (or Wisdom); anything that lacks either is an object and inanimate.